# what does this mean: Said General Custer to his horse

Tags: expressions, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

I came across the phrase 'Said General Custer to his horse' in this Dilbert comic. [image: Dilbert comic]

But I have no idea what it means.

I searched the internet to find what it means but all I could find were pages about George Armstrong Custer some include his horse but none give a really good explanation on what the phrase means.

So what does "Said General Custer to his horse" mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, "*said General Custer to his horse*" is intended to re-interpret the PHB's previous sentence as a quote by General Custer addressed to his own horse.

> "'Stop being such a pessimist," said General Custer to his horse.

General Custer is most famously known for his crushing defeat at the [Battle of the Little Bighorn/Battle of the Greasy Grass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_the_Little_Bighorn) ("Custer's Last Stand"). Dilbert refers to the loss by joking that even General Custer's horse knew that defeat was inevitable: the horse was pessimistic about Custer's chances.

Comment: And horses are [neigh-sayers](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/naysayer).

Comment: My great-grandfather was killed at the Battle of the Little Big Horn. He wasn't involved in the fighting; he was camping nearby, and went over to complain about the noise. :-)